# Show $\ W = (W \cap W_1 ) \ \oplus (W \cap W_2) \oplus \cdots \oplus(W\cap W_k) $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ T: V \rightarrow V $ and $\ p = p_1^{r_1} \cdot p_2^{r_2} \dots p_k^{r_k}  $ be the minimal polynomial. $\ W $ subspace of $\ V, $ and its $\ T $ invariant. I need to show $\ W = (W \cap W_1 ) \ \oplus (W \cap W_2) \oplus \cdots \oplus(W\cap W_k) $

I was thinking maybe:

for every $\ v \in (W \cap Wi) \rightarrow v\in W \land v \in W_i $

and since $\ W_i \cap W_j = \{0\} $ for every $\ i \not = j $
it means that $\ (W \cap W_i) \cap (W \cap W_j) = \{0 \} $ and since $\ W $ is subspace of $\ V $ and $\ W_i $ 's are the direct sum of $\ V $ it must be be true ?

I've found the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836647/v-w-1-oplus-w-2-oplus-oplus-w-s-we-must-have-w-w-1-cap-w-oplus-w). If I'll show that any $\ T $ invariant subspace is a direct sum of some of the eigen spaces will it be enough? How do I show it? Also why does he say that any of the eigen spaces must be contained within $\ W_i $'s isn't it the definition that $\ W_i = \ker(\lambda_i) $ ?